# parse_url defaults to path rather than host

Tags: php

Why does parse_url place domain information in `path` by default, rather than in `host`?

for example:

```
$url = 'www.example.com';
$parsed_url = parse_url($url);
```

If I do a `var_dump` on $parsed_url I get this:

```
array (size=1)
    'path' => string 'www.example.com' (length=15)
```

By default, shouldn't that be in `host`? If I prepend `http://` to the value in $url, it distributes the information as expected.

Comment: A URL also needs a protocol, like HTTP / FTP / ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition a URL must contain a protocol/scheme like `http://`.

> Partial URLs are also accepted, parse_url() **tries its best** to parse
>   them correctly.

Try this to check for `http://` and if not add it:

```
$url = strpos($url, 'http://') !== 0 ? "http://$url" : $url;
```

You might have to check for `https://` as well so either do two checks or a regex would work:

```
$url = preg_match('#^https?://#') ? $url : "http://$url";
```

Comment: Right, I get that, which is part of what I'm trying to use this for. It's part of some form input validation. But I can't make other people put http:// in front of a url when they fill out the form.

Comment: Right, so the above lines takes care of that.